# postgresql windows external authentication

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I have to implement some safety authentication rules on postgresql DB  ( with a windows server)like: users  not used for a period longer than three months will be locked or postgres enforces account lockout after a set number of failed login attempts.....

Using authentication "standard" ( md5 on pg_hba.conf) I think is not possible..but I think that with PAM I could do 
but  PAM does not exist on win.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot Gian

Comment: If you don't mind writing a bit of C code, you could probably do this with an [authentication hook](https://github.com/gleu/Hooks-in-PostgreSQL/blob/master/examples/my_client_auth/my_client_auth.c)

Comment: I still work on it, can you share somre info...? please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy, but can be done with an LDAP interface to AD.  Personally, I would load the whole mess into an Ubuntu or Centos vm

Comment: Sorry I can not do this